# Xpath: Wildcards for descendant nodes not working

Tags: xpath

**Desired output**: 3333

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="name"> 
      <p class="desc">Intel</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
 Other tr tags


  <tr>
    <td class="tel"> 
      <p class="desc">3333</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

I want to select the last tr tag after the tr tag that has "Intel" in the p tag
**//tbody//tr[td[p[contains(text(),'Intel')]]]/followingsibling::tr[position()=last()]//p/text()**

The above works but I don't wish to reference td and p explicitly. I tried wildcards ? or *, but it doesn't work.

**//tbody//tr[?[?[contains(text(),'Intel')]]]/followingsibling::tr[position()=last()]//p/text()**

Answer (score 3):

*"...which contains a text node equal to 'Intel'"*

```
//tbody/tr[.//text() = 'Intel']/following-sibling::tr[last()]/td/p/text()
```

*"...which contains only the string 'Intel', once you remove all insignificant white-space"*

```
//tbody/tr[normalize-space() = 'Intel']/following-sibling::tr[last()]/td/p/text()
```

I think the key take-away here is that you can use descendant paths (`//`) *and* pay attention to context in predicates once you make them relative (`.//`).

Comment: While yr solution works. What if I want to use contains text? I tried but doesn't work //tbody/tr[.//[contains(text(), 'Intel')]]/following-sibling::tr[last()]/td/p/text()

Comment: Solved with //tbody/tr[.//*[contains(text(), 'Intel')]]/following-sibling::tr[last()]/td/p/text()

Comment: @123456 Better: `//tbody/tr[.//text()[contains(., 'Intel')]]/...`, if you want to be *that* specific, but probably best would be `//tbody/tr[contains(., 'Intel')]/...`